# PHP cURL JSON eBay API request

Tags: php, json, curl, ebay-api

I'm trying to call eBay's Shopping API using PHP and cURL and returning the response in JSON format. It works when I put the URL in the browser directly but it doesn't within PHP. I don't want to work with XML. JSON is easier. Any suggestions?

```
$Url ="http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetMultipleItems&responseencoding=JSON&appid=MyAppId&siteid=0&version=525&ItemID=290585620456,290683575886&IncludeSelector=Details,ShippingCosts,Variations";

//check if you have curl loaded
if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");

$ch=curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($r);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you not get any data? The wrong data? A blank page?

Comment: Your code displays `string(285) "{"Timestamp":"2012-09-08T18:21:45.632Z","Ack":"Failure","Errors":[{"ShortMessage":"Application ID invalid.","LongMessage":"Application ID invalid.","ErrorCode":"1.20","SeverityCode":"Error","ErrorClassification":"RequestError"}],"Build":"E789_CORE_BUNDLED_15285085_R1","Version":"789"}"` for me. This looks like json :o

Comment: hmmm ... that's weird. It works now. I can't believe I spent an hour on that. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
   json_encode($response_string);
```

this will parse the response string into json object.

if you want basic array instead of json object, then use

```
json_decode($responce_str, true);
```

this will return an associative array.